# iOS navigation app with multiple & offline maps: which library to use?

Tags: ios, frameworks, maps, location, libraries

i'm stuck with problem of what lib to choose for my nav app project.

At the moment there is:
1) route-me
2) Alpstein route-me
3) mapbox-ios-sdk

What is the difference between them all? What to choose as a foundation for navigation app?

Requirements for my app:
1) Multiple maps available
2) Multiple selected areas of different maps to work offline

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you've got:

Route-me/Route-me
     Alpstein/Route-me (branch from Route-me/Route-Me)
           Mapbox/Mapbox-ios-sdk (branch from Alpstein/Route-Me)

Although Alpstein is a fork from the original route-me it has derailed a lot. Feature-wise it's not that different, but has lots of performance improvements, and the API itself is different (and better IMHO).

Also, the Alpstein has more activity in Github than the original branch, which I find a positive thing.

The mapbox branch is exactly the same as the Alpstein, but includes some specific MapBox features like:

- Ability to load maps from the MapBox cloud storage service natively
- Interaction with the UTFGrid technology.

So, to summon up, I would choose the Alpstein fork if you don't use MapBox specific features, and the MapBox-ios-sdk if you do.

Comment: So MapBox is a superset which includes all the features of Alpstein + their own stuff, or it is a modification with some things have been "cut off"?

Comment: It's a superset including all the Alpstein features, at least currently :)